# Redefining the "Object" Keyword in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, keyword

How bad is it to redefine special words (technically predefined global variables) like `Object` in Node.js? I have a `mongoose` model I want to call "Object" because, well, it represents an object, and the convention for `mongoose` seems to be that the models are uppercase. However, I noticed that `Object` is a keyword in JavaScript. I tried to use Node itself to see exactly what the `Object` keyword does, based on what the JavaScript source code says about it. However, when I run `console.log(Object.toString());` in the Node shell, it returns `function Object() { [native code] };`. Other special words, like `Boolean` and `String`, produce similar output when logged. I would go into the Node source code, but I unfortunately have not had the privilege of learning C or C++.

Therefore, **what would the repercussions of redefining JavaScript keywords like `Object`, `Array`, or `Number`?** I am mainly asking in the context of Node.js, but information about JavaScript in general would certainly be helpful. I will likely not use these variables as they were originally intended, which I believe is as a wrapper object for each type (`Array` for arrays, `Number` for numbers, etc.), but would there be any other unintended consequences in using them for a completely different purpose?

Comment: `Object` is not a keyword.  And, don't do that; it'll be horribly confusing.

Comment: It's some sort of special word. I'm not sure what it's called if it's not a keyword.

Comment: It's just a predefined global variable.

Comment: Just call it `ObjectModel` instead.

Comment: OK, but what happens if I use `Object`? Does my computer blow up?

Comment: Don't even think about trying to replace something as fundamental as `Object`.  Bad, very bad.  If I worked the same place you did, I'd immediately reject that code in any sort of code review and if you checked it in that way and I was your boss you'd get a significant reprimand and a rollback of your code.  Tons of fundamental things could break and all because you have a favorite "name" for something.  No.  Pick a non-conflicting name.  A little imagination can easily find a perfectly suitable name.

Comment: It's not for a company. I am doing this website on my own, mainly for practice for when I land a job. Point taken, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do this. Simple example how things will blow up:

```
@jack:~$ node
> Object = ''
''
> var c = {}
undefined
> c

util.js:222
  var keys = Object.keys(value);
                    ^
TypeError: Object  has no method 'keys'
    at formatValue (util.js:222:21)
    at Object.inspect (util.js:140:10)
    at REPLServer.self.writer (repl.js:177:19)
    at finish (repl.js:291:38)
    at repl.js:251:15
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:122:7)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
```

The same thing will happen if you do this in a script. You should prefix (or namespace) your version of these objects instead.

Comment: If you make it a local variable, it won't be so bad.  (But it still isn't a good idea)

Comment: I think I'll just do what @JohnnyHK said and use `ObjectModel`. Just wanted to know why it was so bad.